# Not able to add columns to Document Library from Visual Studio template

Tags: sharepoint-2013, document-library

I am trying to create new document library from SharePoint project template from Visual Studio 2015.

While doing so I am able to create Document Library Template and Instance. Also if I deploy solution to one of my site it creates list as well. Strange thing is if I add a column to the template and then deploy it creates the list but does not create new custom column.

Below is the schema file for the template.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<List xmlns:ows="Microsoft SharePoint" Title="SharedDocuments" Direction="$Resources:Direction;" Url="SharedDocuments" BaseType="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/" EnableContentTypes="TRUE">
  <MetaData>
    <ContentTypes>
      <ContentType ID="0x0101000dba2955561e4de0a115152637e9f8e2" Name="ListFieldsContentType">
        <FieldRefs>
          <FieldRef ID="{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247}" Name="Title" />
          <FieldRef ID="{4b1bf6c6-4f39-45ac-acd5-16fe7a214e5e}" Name="TemplateUrl" />
          <FieldRef ID="{cd1ecb9f-dd4e-4f29-ab9e-e9ff40048d64}" Name="xd_ProgID" />
          <FieldRef ID="{fbf29b2d-cae5-49aa-8e0a-29955b540122}" Name="xd_Signature" />
          <FieldRef ID="{e52012a0-51eb-4c0c-8dfb-9b8a0ebedcb6}" Name="Combine" />
          <FieldRef ID="{5d36727b-bcb2-47d2-a231-1f0bc63b7439}" Name="RepairDocument" />
          <FieldRef ID="{8f838bdc-4b95-4b26-b86f-3025d2df964f}" Name="TestColumn" />
        </FieldRefs>
      </ContentType>
      <ContentTypeRef ID="0x0101">
        <Folder TargetName="Forms/Document" />
      </ContentTypeRef>
      <ContentTypeRef ID="0x0120" />
    </ContentTypes>
    <Fields>
      <Field ID="{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247}" Type="Text" Name="Title" ShowInNewForm="FALSE" ShowInFileDlg="FALSE" DisplayName="$Resources:core,Title;" Sealed="TRUE" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="Title"></Field>
      <Field ID="{4b1bf6c6-4f39-45ac-acd5-16fe7a214e5e}" Type="Text" Name="TemplateUrl" DisplaceOnUpgrade="TRUE" DisplayName="$Resources:core,Template_Link;" XName="TemplateUrl" Filterable="TRUE" Sortable="TRUE" Hidden="TRUE" FromBaseType="TRUE" PITarget="mso-infoPathSolution" PIAttribute="href" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="TemplateUrl"></Field>
      <Field ID="{cd1ecb9f-dd4e-4f29-ab9e-e9ff40048d64}" Type="Text" Name="xd_ProgID" DisplaceOnUpgrade="TRUE" DisplayName="$Resources:core,Html_File_Link;" XName="ProgID" Filterable="TRUE" Sortable="TRUE" Hidden="TRUE" FromBaseType="TRUE" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="xd_ProgID"></Field>
      <Field ID="{fbf29b2d-cae5-49aa-8e0a-29955b540122}" Type="Boolean" Group="_Hidden" Name="xd_Signature" DisplaceOnUpgrade="TRUE" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="xd_Signature" DisplayName="$Resources:core,Xml_signed;" XName="{FBF29B2D-CAE5-49aa-8E0A-29955B540122}" Filterable="TRUE" Sortable="TRUE" Sealed="TRUE" Hidden="TRUE" FromBaseType="TRUE" ReadOnly="TRUE"></Field>
      <Field ID="{e52012a0-51eb-4c0c-8dfb-9b8a0ebedcb6}" ReadOnly="TRUE" Type="Computed" Name="Combine" DisplaceOnUpgrade="TRUE" DisplayName="$Resources:core,Merge;" Filterable="FALSE" Sortable="FALSE" Hidden="TRUE" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="Combine">
        <FieldRefs>
          <FieldRef Name="FSObjType" Key="Primary" />
          <FieldRef Name="EncodedAbsUrl" />
          <FieldRef Name="TemplateUrl" />
        </FieldRefs>
      </Field>
      <Field ID="{5d36727b-bcb2-47d2-a231-1f0bc63b7439}" ReadOnly="TRUE" Type="Computed" Name="RepairDocument" DisplaceOnUpgrade="TRUE" DisplayName="$Resources:core,Relink;" Filterable="FALSE" Sortable="FALSE" Hidden="TRUE" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="RepairDocument">
        <FieldRefs>
          <FieldRef Name="FSObjType" Key="Primary" />
          <FieldRef Name="ID" />
        </FieldRefs>
      </Field>
      <Field Name="TestColumn" ID="{8f838bdc-4b95-4b26-b86f-3025d2df964f}" DisplayName="TestColumn" Type="Text" />
    </Fields>
    <Views>
    --Removed--
    </Views>
    <Forms>
      <Form Type="DisplayForm" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" Url="Forms/DispForm.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
      <Form Type="EditForm" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" Url="Forms/EditForm.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
      <Form Type="NewForm" Url="Forms/Upload.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
    --Removed--
    </Forms>
  </MetaData>
</List>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you upload a document in a Document Library there's an option for you to choose the Content Type, choose your custom Content Type and you'll see the fields you defined.

Comment: I totally forgot to comment the fix. To fix the issue I had to update TemplateType to unique value and then it worked.